# My phone is (apparently) hijacked by a virus

Tags: malware, huawei

I have a Huawei Honor 4c and I wanted to update it to lollipop, but it had to be done manually.

I downloaded the file I thought I needed but I decided not to install it, as it had a strange name - jenkins something, so I deleted it.

A few days later I start getting these log files. I don't pay attention to them but soon all my pictures, videos, etc disappear. I freak out and restart my phone but nothing changes. I connect it to my pc but my pc does not recognize it as a phone, but as a media player and it says that my phone's a linux.

So, I get on my phone, delete all the log files and everything else I find suspicious and download *cm security*, *app lock*, *kaspersky*, etc but none of them, apart from kaspersky, detect anything. However, kaspersky loses the trace a few moments after it has detected it, so I decide to reset my factory settings.

After I've done that, a few days later these log files appear again this time threatening me that if I delete them and the other files I deleted, all my photoes will be gone forever. I then proceed to reset my factory settings again this time without using google play's back up and any internet connection.

This kind of seemed to work /despite my system apps and files running on that jenkins platform/ until my phone starts downloading this strange file every couple of hours. When it downloads it, *cm security* says it's safe but I delete it. Nevertheless, I was away from my phone for more than 5 hours during which it downloaded the file again and now the virus is very much alive... it has even managed to get through *cm's app locker*...

Also, I feel I should mention I noticed that my phone doesn't always have an ip address which I think is kind of strange, I don't have an sd card, and I have backed up my photoes with google plus, although it's not very efficient as I don't have a strong working connection at all times.

Please help me, I don't know what to do, nor do I understand much regarding smartphones.

Comment: That jenkins file, where did you download it from? You didn't install it, but did you try to execute it or just stored it on your phone?

Comment: I don't remember where I downloaded it from, and before deleting it, I think I accidentally executed it.

Answer (score 0):

While I do not know exactly what virus is causing this, it does appear that it has broken its way into the OS itself. A factory reset won't help you now. I would recommend you do not put **any** personal information on this device until you can clear out the virus.

At this point you have 2 options:

1. If the device is under warranty, see what the manufacturer will do for you. They will probably not help you, but it's worth a shot.
2. Flash the OS of the phone. This can be a risky procedure, but if done carefully and exactly as the tutorial you find for your device says you should be okay. Doing this also requires you to root the device, which will invalidate the warranty. At this point, you would flash a custom recovery and flash either the stock rom or an alternate rom such as cyanogenmod or paranoid Android. Look up tutorials on how to do this for your device.

Sorry to break the bad news.